# Is there a way to disable the minutes or hours selection only for html5 type=time?

Tags: javascript, html

HTML5 `type=time` has a property *disabled* which disables the field, but is there any specific way to disable only the hours or only the minutes from the field?

```
<input type='time' />
```

Comment: What did u try ?

Comment: @PhilAndelhofs, was thinking to block using css, but could not get hold of the dom element specific to the hours or minutes entry field.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can definitely lock the minutes so they can't be changed and only hours can be adjusted, just change the step:

For example:

```
<input type='time'  step='3600'/>
```

```html
<input type='time'  step='3600'/>
```

To accomplish only using minutes, you can technically do this by maxing and mining the time:

```html
<input type='time'  max='00:59' min='00:00'/>
```

Comment: Awsome, that was quick! Thanks @Bug

Comment: @sSD No problem, if this is the right answer to you then you can mark it as the solution under to the left of the post :)

Comment: The solution only blocks the minutes or seconds, but how to disable only the hours keeping the minutes enabled?

Comment: @sSD Added a way to disable hours and keep minutes :)

Comment: I can still select the hours opening the time picker, am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

`step` is the attribute you are looking for.

The `step` attribute indicate what the minimum increment should be in seconds. If set to 60, the increment will always be 60 seconds - in other words, seconds cannot be changed. To make the minutes too cannot be changed, use `step="3600"`.

```html
<form>
  <label for="appt-time">Choose an appointment time: </label>
  <input id="appt-time" type="time" name="appt-time" step="3600">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you! Tried it when @Bug posted it below, and worked like a charm!